# What is it called when you move chords a step up or down?

Tags: theory, terminology, transposition

What is the name or concept that explains or refers to when chords become other chords if you move them one step up or down? For example, B♭ Major becomes A Major once it's moved a step down, and vice versa (A major becomes B♭ Major when it's moved a step up).  Is this the same as key modulations as well?

Answer (score 5):

The concept you refer to is called [Transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(music)), which is moving one or more notes up or down by a given amount. You can transpose individual chords, or phrases, or entire pieces.

For example, if you have a piece in C major, and transpose it up a whole step, the resulting piece will be in D major. If the piece modulates partway through, for example, from C to G (up a fifth), then the *transposed* piece will modulate from D to A (also up a fifth).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, also how could i incorporate transposition into a key modulation is it possible?

Comment: I already answered what happens when you transpose a piece that has a modulation.

Comment: thank you also is there anyway you can give more of an example of the modulations from one key to another, and part way modulations in more of a simpler form, im really new to the theory. much appreciated .

Comment: Modulation is not the same as transposition, and works entirely differently.  Transposition is playing an entire piece of music in a different key.  Modulation is moving from one key to another inside a piece of music.  Don't think of them as different aspects of the same thing.  The simplest way to modulate is to play a chord which is common to the key you are leaving and the key you want to go to, and follow it with more chords from the target key.  For example C F C G (common chord) D7 G, and now you can go on in G.  Or a (lower case=minor) E7 a F G7 C will move you from a to C.